# Read style items programmatically

Tags: android, resources, styles, android-styles

A style defined in XML resources cannot be "applied" at runtime.
So, given a style name, I would like to read the style items one by one, interpret them and apply them programmatically to selected widgets.

Because sometimes, a user may want to change the style of some widgets at runtime an I want that style to be exactly as the one defined in the resources.

The only reason I want to do it this way is to preserve consistency between the style defined in the XML resource and the style I appply at runtime.

How can I read the style items? I know one way: to parse the XML file myself, but maybe there are some built in methods to directly read the style I am not aware of.